# Attempted to drop columns containing foreign keys and received error message

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys, sql-drop

I am using phpMyAdmin version 3.3.10.3 to manage my database.

I am using InnoDB and foreign key contraints.

I have attempted to drop several columns from a table. These columns are foreign keys referencing other tables.

```
ALTER TABLE `product`
  DROP `c_status_id`,
  DROP `o_certification_id`,
  DROP `g_free_certification_id`,
  DROP `gm_certification_id`,
  DROP `n_certification_id`;
```

Upon attempt of the query I received the following error message.

```
#1025 - Error on rename of ' /#sql-ea2_38d9f' to ' /product' (errno: 150
```

Comment: Also so this in the error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1025 (errno: 150) - not very descriptive or easy to google for.  I posted more error text here: http://wp.me/p3XdjT-11

Answer (score 2):

You must first drop the foreign key relationship before you drop the column referenced in the relationship.

```
ALTER TABLE 'TABLE_NAME' DROP FOREIGN KEY 'NAME_OF_FOREIGN_KEY'
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html